# Is there a way to render new paragraphs from a YAML multi-line key?

Tags: yaml

I have a YAML key set up like so:

```
en:
  info: |
    Hello!

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

The intended render is:

> Hello!
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

However, in reality, this is rendered like so:

> Hello! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

So, my question is: Is it possible to for YAML to be rendered the way I want it to be? Or, do I need to create a separate key for each paragraph?

Comment: What language / parser are you using? What you have (using `|`) is correct for what you want according to the spec, and when I test using Ruby (with the Psych parser) the result is your expected result.

Comment: As @matt notes, `|` will preserve newlines. I suspect the real problem is that you're inserting the result directly onto an HTML document, and whitespace is collapsed by default in HTML. If that's the case, this isn't a YAML problem.

Comment: @Jordan you are right. It’s not a YAML problem and the whitespace is being collapsed by the HTML. 

I am using Jekyll with the Liquid templating language. So, to get my intended render I simply had to use the `markdownify` filter on the Liquid markup.

See https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203441346-Add-Markdownify-filter-to-Liquid-Markup

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation of YAML ruby implementation](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html), you can use it like this:

```
clipped: |
    This has one newline.



same as "clipped" above: "This has one newline.\n"

stripped: |-
    This has no newline.



same as "stripped" above: "This has no newline."

kept: |+
    This has four newlines.



same as "kept" above: "This has four newlines.\n\n\n\n"
```

It will generate:

```
{  
  'clipped' => "This has one newline.\n", 
  'same as "clipped" above' => "This has one newline.\n", 
  'stripped' => 'This has no newline.', 
  'same as "stripped" above' => 'This has no newline.', 
  'kept' => "This has four newlines.\n\n\n\n", 
  'same as "kept" above' => "This has four newlines.\n\n\n\n" 
}
```

Example taken [from here](http://www.yaml.org/YAML_for_ruby.html#three_trailing_newlines_in_literals).